# Where in the python docs does it allow the `in` operator to be chained?

Tags: python, operators, comparison-operators

I recently discovered that the following returns `True`:

```
'a' in 'ab' in 'abc'
```

I'm aware of the python comparison chaining such as `a < b < c`, but I can't see anything in the docs about this being legal.

Is this an accidental feature in the implementation of CPython, or is this behaviour specified?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is fully specified behaviour, not an accidental feature. Operator chaining is defined in the [*Comparison operators* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

`in` is one of the comparison operators; from the same section:

> ```
> comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "<>" | "!="
>                    | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
> ```

No exceptions are made for combinations that may not make much sense.

The specific expression you used as an example is thus executed as `'a' in 'ab' and 'ab' in 'abc'`, with the  `'ab'` literal only being executed (loaded) once.

Comment: I was looking at the [comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) section on a different page, which does not list `in`

Comment: @Eric see the bottom of that section: *Two more operations with the same syntactic priority, `in` and `not in`, are supported only by sequence types (below).* Because of that limitation they are not listed in the table.