# Multiple repeated `in` keyword

Tags: python

By mistake I have used more than one `in` keyword in an expression, but the code still works.

What is the meaning of:

```
"a" in "bar" in "foo"   # in ... ?
```

naively I thought that this was equivalent to `("a" in "bar") in "foo"` or `"a" in ("bar" in "foo")` but it is not the case since both are not valid. I get the same behaviour in python2 or 3.

Comment: probably `'a' in 'bar' and 'bar' in 'foo'` following a similar logic as `x < y < z`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: why? I can't find it in the documentation. And what is the meaning of `"a" in "b" in "c" in "'d" ...` ?

Comment: @RuggeroTurra By extension, that would be `("a" in "b") and ("b" in c") and ("c" in "d")`.  And `"bar" in "a" in "aaa"` *does* evaluate to `False`, so I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: @RuggeroTurra because `'bar' in 'a'` is `False`. My analogy was confusing. I meant that there are two separate checks; the result of the first does not partake in the second.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38296689/2301450

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`in` is considered a comparison operator, and from [Python's documentation for them](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if *a*, *b*, *c*, ..., *y*, *z* are expressions and *op1*, *op2*, ..., *opN* are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

Answer (score 4):

Python evaluates from left to right (you can control the flow / grouping with brackets, tho), and comparison operators can be chained arbitrarily so an expression:

```
"a" in "bar" in "foo" in "baz"
```

Essentially ends up as:

```
"a" in "bar" and "bar" in "foo" and "foo" in "baz"
```

Which resolves to `False`.

Comment: if it were just from left to right it would be `(("a" in "bar") in "foo") in "baz"`

Comment: The evaluation order isn't the crux of the question.

Comment: @jamesdlin - it matters quite a bit with comparison operator chaining because evaluation breaks the moment it encounters a false comparison - `"f" in "bar" in None` is perfectly valid as the first (LTR order) comparison fails and Python breaks out, however `"f" in "foo" in None` will result in a `TypeError`.

Comment: @zwer I didn't say it didn't matter.  It's just not what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to mean the following:

`("a" in "bar") and ("bar" in "foo")` - or `False`

The following might help:

- `"a" in "bar" in "foo"` => `False`
- `"a" in "bar" in "foobar"` => `True`
- `"b" in "bar" in "foobar"` => `True`
- `"c" in "bar" in "foobar"` => `False`

I thought at first that it might have been `"a" in ("bar" in "foo")`, but that obviously would return the following:

`TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable`

Because `("bar" in "foo")` returns `False`

**Edit** Fixed obvious typos

Comment: `"b" in "bar" in "foo"`  => `False`. Should be `False` not `True`

Comment: Is there an extra `in` after the `and` in your first code line?

Comment: Apologies, had a couple of typos in there - should make sense now :)